# suitable data type for 20 digit numbers

Tags: java

what data type is suitable for a given 20 digit numbers like `12111111111111111111` and could be converted to binary?

I tried `long` but it's goes out of range.

Comment: To get binary String you can call BigInteger.toString(2)

Answer (score 3):

[`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is for "Immutable arbitrary-precision integers" - should fit your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("12111111111111111111");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("12111111111111111112");
System.out.println(b1.add(b2));
System.out.println(" binary format of b1 is : " + b1.toString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well u can use bigInteger that is having large length of the number that what u want.

try this.

```
java.math.BigInteger bignumber = new BigInteger("1211111111111255511236");
```

hope that will help.